# How to configure and use Serilog in ASP.NET Core 6?

Tags: c#, serilog, .net-6.0, sentry, ilogger

Since the recently introduced new structure of the Program.cs startup code, the documentation confuses me a bit.

In the officially provided [`Serilog.AspNetCore` example](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore) and in the [`Serilog.Sentry` example](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/blob/main/samples/Sentry.Samples.AspNetCore.Serilog/Program.cs), they use `.UseSerilog()` on the `WebHostBuilder`. I cannot find this method.

This is what I have tried:

```
using Serilog;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// adding services...

builder.Logging.AddSerilog(); // <- is this even necessary?

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

// configure request pipeline
app.Run();
```

But how / where can I **configure the sinks**, e.g. Debug, Console, Sentry, ...? I have the feeling that docs are a bit outdated or I am just a bit blind.

Comment: see also https://blog.datalust.co/using-serilog-in-net-6/

Comment: look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76641381/how-to-add-serilog-in-program-cs-in-net6/76668977#76668977

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You'll need to make sure you have the following packages installed:

- Serilog
- Serilog.Extensions.Hosting (this provides the `.UseSerilog` extension method. If you have the Serilog.AspNetCore package, you do not need to explicitly include this)

Then you'll need a `using`:

```cs
using Serilog;
```

Which should allow you to access `.UseSerilog` via `builder.Host`:

```cs
using Serilog;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Host.UseSerilog();
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

You can use a different overload to get the hosting context, services, and configuration. From there you can configure sinks, etc.:

```cs
builder.Host.UseSerilog((hostContext, services, configuration) => {
    configuration.WriteTo.Console();
});
```

Comment: Just as a sidenote, from the official GitHub Readme of `Serilog.Extensions.Hosting`: _ASP.NET Core applications should consider using `Serilog.AspNetCore` instead, which bundles this package and includes other ASP.NET Core-specific features._ .

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the `builder.Host.UseSerilog();`!

Comment: Great, manually adding `using Serilog;` did the trick. Before I would not get a intellisense suggestion for `.UseSerilog()`

Answer (score 10):

I used the following code snippet to fix the issue. I added it to Program.cs

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
.Enrich.FromLogContext()
.CreateLogger();

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);
```

[link](https://www.claudiobernasconi.ch/2022/01/28/how-to-use-serilog-in-asp-net-core-web-api/)

Comment: thanks, didn't realize there is a ClearProviders, otherwise it throws duplicated logs

Answer (score 3):

#### On top of Program.cs class paste the following:-

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.MinimumLevel.Debug()
.WriteTo.Console()
.WriteTo.File("logs/rumble-.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
.CreateLogger();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working local logging configuration.
First configure logger:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.File(
    path: "c:\\hotellisting\\log\\log-.txt",
    outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
    rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
    restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Warning
    ).CreateLogger();
```

Then adding Serilog to builder logging:

```
builder.Logging.AddSerilog();
```

To Logging:

```
Log.Error("error occured while bla bla");
```

Answer (score -2):

```
//serilog
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    
    .WriteTo.File(new JsonFormatter(),@"logs\log-.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Hour)
    .MinimumLevel.Error()
    .WriteTo.Console(new JsonFormatter())
    .CreateLogger();
builder.Host.UseSerilog(Log.Logger);
var app = builder.Build();
```