# How to add Serilog in Program.cs in .NET6?

Tags: c#, backend, serilog, asp.net-core-6.0

I put  `using Serilog`   on the top within each class where I want to add logs. But, when I want to add logs in Program.cs in order to log the information / error for DB connection, I find that the logs cannot be displayed either on console or local files.

This is my Serilog settings in appsettings.json:

```
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    },
    "Enrich": [
      "FromLogContext"
    ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "../logs/dev/dev.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "outputTemplate": "{Level:w5} [{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff}] [{UserId}] [{ResourceId}] >> {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "{Level:w5} [{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HyH:mm:ss,fff}] [{UserId}] [{ResourceId}] >> {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

This is my Program.cs:

```
using MyProject.Repositories;
using MyProject.Services;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Serilog;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static string? env = String.Empty;
        private static string connect = String.Empty;
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Decide which environment this App is gonna use

            
            // 2. Getting Env var from deployment side approach
            env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SERVER_ENVIRONMENT");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(env))
            {
                env = "dev";
            }

            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", true, true);

            builder.Host.UseSerilog((hostContext, services, configuration) =>
            {
                configuration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostContext.Configuration);
            });

            // Add services to the container.

            builder.Services.AddControllers();

            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<ILikeService, LikeService>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<LdapService>();
            

            // User SQL Server
            if (env.Equals("dev"))
            {
                connect = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Connection");
            }
            else if (env.Equals("pre") || env.Equals("prod"))
            {
                // do something
            }



            /// This is the block that I'm not able to get logs displayed!-----------------------------------
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connect))
            {
                try
                {
                    //// not displaying
                    Log.Debug("this is a debug msg");

                    //// not displaying
                    Log.Information("Before testing connect...");
                    connection.Open();

                    //// not displaying
                    Log.Information("Connection successful!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Success");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //// not displaying                    
                    Log.Error("Connection failed: {ErrorMessage}", ex.Message);
                    
                }
            }

//////-----------------------------------
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<LikeDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(connect));
            builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

           


            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }

            app.UsePathBase("/my-app");
            app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), appBuilder =>
            {
                appBuilder.UseMiddleware<ApiHeaderMiddleware>();
            });

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();


            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

            using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                try
                {
                    var context = services.GetRequiredService<LikeDbContext>();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred creating the DB.");
                }
            }

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

As the log in Controller, Service classes are all behaving as expected, I'm thinking whether I should extract that code block into a class and add the class into DI container.

Comment: Suspicion: `IHostBuilder.UseSerilog` internally calls `ConfigureServices` with a lambda expression which has delayed execution. All these configuration expressions are only called by`builder.Build()`, so the Serilog configuration you are expecting isn't set up yet at the point it's called. Will attempt to repro and make an answer if correct

Answer (score 1):

Try registering like this instead of using `builder.Host.UseSerilog()`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
    // set default minimum level
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .CreateLogger();

Log.Debug("this is a debug msg");
Log.Information("Before testing connect...");
Log.Information("Connection successful!");
Log.Error("Connection failed");
//...
```

appsettings.json:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Enrich": [
      "FromLogContext"
    ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "../logs/dev/dev.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "outputTemplate": "{Level:w5} [{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff}] [{UserId}] [{ResourceId}] >> {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "{Level:w5} [{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HyH:mm:ss,fff}] [{UserId}] [{ResourceId}] >> {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Test Result:

Console:

[image]

File:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

in `Program.cs` file to read configuration add below lines for `builder`

```
    builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
     .WriteTo.Console()  //To write in Console 
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration));
```

for request logging add below lines after `var app = builder.Build();`

```
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
```

Configure `appsetings.json` accordingly how you want logging and where you want to like `SQL`,`.txt file`,`seq`...etc

follow below lines to log into txt file

```
"Serilog": {
"MinimumLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Override": {
    "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
  }
},
"Filter": [
  {
    "Name": "ByExcluding",
    "Args": { "expression": "@mt = 'An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.'" }
  }
],
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      //"path": "./logs/log-.txt", // for with in the project
      "path": "C:/Logs/log-.txt", //For external path
      "rollingInterval": "Day"
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Seq",
    "Args": { "serverUrl": "http://localhost:5341" }
  }
]
}
```

Comment: Hello  Upender i am using your code, its working fine but the issue is my debugging console remains blank(Dark). Did you face same issue ?